# Retrieve TOTP seed from tokens and timestamps

Tags: hash, password-cracking, brute-force, totp

I recently switched to or added the option to use time-based one time passwords, TOTP, as the second factor for some services I use. It got me wondering if it's possible to retrieve the secret seed if I gather enough tokens and their time stamps. Is this possible? Are there automated tools to do that? And are there faster methods than to brute force the seed?

From what I understand it takes the seed and the time and sends it through a hashing algorithm, usually SHA-1, and then somehow mangles it up into a sequence of numbers, usually length 6. So it should be possible to at least brute force the key.

How can I do that?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/209816/70406